# Select one row per id, with condition in nonid field | Magento select Shipping Address

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

i have a Dataset that looks like this

```
parent_id        address_type
        1        billing
        1        shipping
        8        billing
        429      billing
        429      shipping
        429      vendor
```

How can i select those rows who have address_type='shipping'
and if there is no address_type 'shipping' select the address_type='billing' instead

The result should look like this:

```
parent_id        address_type
        1        shipping
        8        billing
        429      shipping
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why does `429 vendor` appear in your desired output? Shouldn't it be `429 shipping`?

Comment: We are using the udropship extension.
But even if you skip this one: The question unfortunately remains the same...

Comment: You said you want to `select rows who have address_type = 'shippping'` and 429 has shipping but it is not in your result. Can you explain why.

Comment: My Mistake, sorry. You are absolutely right.
Now i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to arrive at this result would be to use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT * FROM Table t 
WHERE t.address_type = 'shipping'

UNION aLL

SELECT * FROM Table t 
WHERE t.address_type = 'billing' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table t1 
                    WHERE t.id = t1.id AND t1.address_type = 'shipping')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select parent_id, address_type
from YourTable
where address_type = 'shipping'
union all
select parent_id, address_type
from YourTable
where address_type = 'billing'
  and parent_id not in (select parent_id, address_type
                        from YourTable
                        where address_type = 'shipping')
order by parent_id;
```